# Add Site Name to column in NewEdit Form using Client object model

Tags: development, client-object-model, jsom

I've been able to Get the site name (adding this to editform via CEWP) but I don't know how to modify the script to be able to update the field ProjectName with the Site Name. Any ideas? Thanks so much! -Adam

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebSiteData, "sp.js");  

var context = null;  
var web = null;  


 function getWebSiteData() {  
        context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
        web = context.get_web();  
        context.load(web);  

context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod), Function.createDelegate(this, 

this.onFailureMethod));  

  }  
function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {  
        alert('Check it out Ivy, title derived from the SharePoint Client Object Model (ECMAScripts API): ' + 

web.get_title() );  
    }  
    function onFaiureMethodl(sender, args) {  
        alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `onSuccessMethod` with below one with proper id:

```
function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {  

document.getElementById("your input control's id").value = web.get_title();
    }
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Your are awesome, thank you!

Comment: Happy to help you. Please mark- approve the answer and upvote as well :)